# Efficient accessing in sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with recommender systems but I'm struggling with the access times of the scipy sparse matrices.

In this case, I'm implementing *TrustSVD* so I need an efficient structure to operate both in columns and rows (CSR, CSC). I've thought about using both structures, dictionaries,... but either way this is always too slow, especially compared with the numpy matrix operations.

```py
for u, j in zip(*ratings.nonzero()):
    items_rated_by_u = ratings[u, :].nonzero()[1]
    users_who_rated_j = ratings[:, j].nonzero()[0]
    # More code...
```

**Extra:**
Each loop takes around 0.033s, so iterating once through 35,000 ratings means to wait 19min per iteration (SGD) and for a minimum of 25 iterations we're talking about 8h. Moreover, here I'm just talking about accessing, if I include the factorization part it would take around 2 days.

Comment: Are the matrices you are using banded? If so, exploiting that could be very helpful. If not, what about a list of list implementation? For a m*n matrix, this has access time~log(n), and fairly space efficient.

Comment: I suspect you need two versions of the matrix (one a transpose), and need to access the underlying data structures directly.

Comment: No, the matrices are not banded. Ratings are uniformly disperse in the matrix (actually some items tend to be more rated than others, but this is not relevant here). The other thing is to use this kind of dual or precomputed structures trading memory for speed. But I've noticed that sparse matrices are also pretty slow so I've thought to use two dictionary of arrays (one per axis). Do you have a faster solution in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you index a sparse matrix, especially just asking for a row or column, it not only has to select the values, but it also has to construct a new sparse matrix.  `np.ndarray` construction is done in compiled code, but most of the sparse construction is pure Python.  The `nonzero()[1]` construct requires converting the matrix to `coo` format and picking the `row` and `col` attributes (look at its code).

I think you could access your row columns faster by looking at the `rows` attribute of the `lil` format, or its transpose:

```
In [418]: sparse.lil_matrix(np.matrix('0,1,0;1,0,0;0,1,1'))
Out[418]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [419]: M=sparse.lil_matrix(np.matrix('0,1,0;1,0,0;0,1,1'))
In [420]: M.A
Out[420]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
In [421]: M.rows
Out[421]: array([[1], [0], [1, 2]], dtype=object)
In [422]: M[1,:].nonzero()[1]
Out[422]: array([0], dtype=int32)
In [423]: M[2,:].nonzero()[1]
Out[423]: array([1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [424]: M.T.rows
Out[424]: array([[1], [0, 2], [2]], dtype=object)
```

You could also access these values in the `csr` format, but it's a bit more complicated

```
In [425]: M.tocsr().indices
Out[425]: array([1, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This speed-up the code around x2-2.5, so the final solution was this plus a caché per axis (users, items).